# RMAN-06169, but only when backing up via OEM 13c

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-12c, rman, oracle-enterprise-manager

When running a Level 1 or Level 0 backup via OEM 13c, the following RMAN error causes the run to fail. (The RMAN script is being ran with proper sysdba credentials from OEM 13c.)

```
RMAN-06169: could not read file header for datafile 2 error reason 5
```

Oracle documentation suggests reason 5 indicates 'Unable to open file'.

However, if I execute the exact same RMAN statement directly on the server, the backup runs fine.

We have removed the database from OEM and decommissioned the agent, the redeployed the agent as well as reinstated the database in OEM, but the error still occurred.

Comment: Are you also connecting to a recovery catalog?

Comment: Yes, we are utilizing a recovery catalog.

Comment: When connecting directly on the server, and invoking `show all;` are the disk parameters the same as when connecting using OEM 13c?  I didn't pay close attention in the RMAN class during the part about using OEM :) but seems like maybe OEM may be looking on the wrong server for the files? Also, can you add a version tag to your question such as oracle-11g etc to specify what version your database you are trying to backup is?

Comment: All applicable configurations in RMAN are identical to what we have set in OEM. Double checked all server locations, but everything is correct. The database is on Oracle12c.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark , but try doing a `crosscheck backup;`  from OEM (if that is possible) and on the server and see what happens. You may have to open a support ticket...

Comment: I went ahead and did a `crosscheck backup;` on the server, to no avail. Thanks for the troubleshooting help. Looks like it is time to resort to Oracle Support.

Comment: When you're logged directly into the server and running the RMAN backups, what account are you using and what permissions does it have on the OS files?  What OS user is OEM using to connect to the server and does that account have sufficient file-level permisisons on the database files (as the error implies an OS permissions issue and not anything related to the database)?  This may be fixed with something as simple as adding the OEM OS user account to the dba (or whatever group you created for Oracle) group on the OS.

Comment: The RMAN jobs run under SYSDBA and when I connect on the server, I connect as 'sys as sysdba'.

Comment: Which tablespace that datafile 2 belongs to? Temp, SYSTEM,USER...?

Comment: I'm sure you have done this, but when connecting via OEM, you verified it connected to the instance you think it did?  (try `report schema` or OEM equivalent/ look at dbid).

Comment: Datafile 2 looks to belong to the SYSAUX tablespace.

Comment: @ca_elrod, you can't connect to a server using `sys as sysdba`, that's how you connect to the database via sqlplus, SQL Developer, or some other oracle client of your choosing.  What account to you use to login to the OS?  root, oracle, etc.?

Comment: Sorry, when on the server, I am logged in as Oracle.

Comment: And what account/named credential does the OEM agent use to log into the server?  Is the OEM account/named credential in the same OS group(s) as the oracle user?

Comment: We are using a named credential that we are calling rmand to act as our least privileged account for OEM to Host connections. It is in the same OS groups as Oracle.

Comment: @ca_elrod: Is the user RMAND(least privileged) member of `DBA` os group? Could you post the output of `[root@host]# id rmand`? Or did you used the same user, the RMAND, to take backup using RMAN CLI?

Comment: `id rmand
uid=5002(rmand) gid=301(dba)`

Comment: Even though it would seem logical that this is a credential / privilege issue, we have over 40 other identical servers with similar databases using the exact same configurations and they are working in OEM without issue.